# Keep the first event with the same events removed until the next different event occurred

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(rep = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                 time = c(0.0000,0.0002,0.0003,0.0015,0.0450,0.07800,0.0000,0.0002,0.0003,0.0015,0.0450,0.07800),
                 Event = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C","A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C"))
```

So the idea is to condense the data by `rep`. Within each `rep`, only the first event is kept in the series with the same events removed until the next different event occurred in the series.

```
df2 <- data.frame(rep = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                 time = c(0.0000,0.0015,0.0450,0.0000,0.0002,0.0450),
                 Event = c("A","B", "C", "A", "B", "C"))
```

I know I would need to start with grouping of `rep` then `Event`

```r
new_df <- df %>%
  group_by(rep) %>%
  slice_head(rle(Event))
```

but I'm worried that `slice_head` would take out too much so looking for opinions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for those rows that are not `duplicated` in columns 1 and 3.

```
df[!duplicated(df[c(1, 3)]), ]
#    rep   time Event
# 1    1 0.0000     A
# 4    1 0.0015     B
# 5    1 0.0450     C
# 7    2 0.0000     A
# 8    2 0.0002     B
# 11   2 0.0450     C
```

#### Update

If you have events with the same label but that actually are different, i.e. something like this

```
df2
#    rep   time Event
# 1    1 0.0000     A
# 2    1 0.0002     A
# 3    1 0.0003     A
# 4    1 0.0015     B
# 5    1 0.0450     C
# 6    1 0.0780     C
# 7    1 0.0002     A
# 8    1 0.0015     B
# 9    1 0.0015     B
# 10   2 0.0000     A
# 11   2 0.0002     B
# 12   2 0.0003     B
# 13   2 0.0015     B
# 14   2 0.0450     C
# 15   2 0.0780     C
# 16   2 0.0000     A
# 17   2 0.0015     B
# 18   2 0.0015     B
```

I would give the events consecutive labels in a `tmp` variable using `rle` in `ave` and filter by that:

```
df2$tmp <- with(df2, ave(Event, rep, FUN=\(x)
                         with(rle(x), rep(LETTERS[seq_len(length(values))], lengths))))
df2[!duplicated(df2[c(1, 4)]), ]
#    rep   time Event tmp
# 1    1 0.0000     A   A
# 4    1 0.0015     B   B
# 5    1 0.0450     C   C
# 7    1 0.0002     A   D
# 8    1 0.0015     B   E
# 10   2 0.0000     A   A
# 11   2 0.0002     B   B
# 14   2 0.0450     C   C
# 16   2 0.0000     A   D
# 17   2 0.0015     B   E
```

You can remove `tmp` if not needed, I left it for demonstration.

---

*Data:*

```
df2 <- structure(list(rep = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), time = c(0, 2e-04, 3e-04, 0.0015, 
0.045, 0.078, 2e-04, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0, 2e-04, 3e-04, 0.0015, 
0.045, 0.078, 0, 0.0015, 0.0015), Event = c("A", "A", "A", "B", 
"C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A", "B", 
"B")), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi @jay.sf i think this would have filtered out too much. The actual data would have repeated Event so it doesnt necessary limit itself to A,B,C. It could be A,A,A,A,B,B,A,A,C,A,A,A,B,B where I would like it to condense to A,B,A,C,A,B.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've tried it on the actual data and it looks like the tmp gets into trouble when n for each rep is approx 20000. tmp on the actual data goes from A to Z then N/A before the next rep.

Comment: @Werrby Instead of `LETTERS[seq_len(length(values))]` use `seq_len(length(values))`

Comment: Thank you very much!! I've accepted the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Event != lag(Event)` to locate where a different event occurred.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(Event != lag(Event) | row_number() == 1, .by = rep)

#   rep   time Event
# 1   1 0.0000     A
# 2   1 0.0015     B
# 3   1 0.0450     C
# 4   2 0.0000     A
# 5   2 0.0002     B
# 6   2 0.0450     C
```